# Laravel app in subfolder corresponding to composer.json

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

Maybe I don't understand some common knowledge... Why folder /app(and others) **should be** in one folder with **composer.json** ?
My question is based on the next framework code part:
File `laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php` has function "**getNamespace**" which is looking for file composer.json in basePath(root for /app, ...)

```
$this->basePath('composer.json')
```

I can't set `$this->namespace` in another way(without App extending). 
My aim, file/folder structure:

`-composer.json
- some`**`Laravel`**`ProjectFolder/app 
- someOtherProjectFolder`

On the same level.

Thx for any anwers :)

Comment: Hm, `base_path()` does _NOT_ include the `/app` folder, that would be `app_path()`. Your project folder is the `base_path` which contains the `/app` folder and the project's `composer.json`

Comment: oh, thx, edited